# Single operation to check for a key and get in Java Map

Tags: java, dictionary, primitive

I want to check if `Map<Integer, Integer>` contains a particular `key`. In case it exists in the `Map` retrieve its corresponding value. But it requires two operations as show below. First one to check if the the key is present using `containsKey()`. And second operation for retrieve using `get()`.

```
    int value = 0;
    if(pageMap.containsKey(key)) {
        value = pageMap.get(key);
    }
```

So I replaced `int` with an `Integer` so I can capture value returned from `get()` and check it for `null`. If it is null we skip `IF` block, otherwise the code inside the block is executed. I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it i.e using an `Object Reference` data type in place of a `primitive` data type to minimize multiple querying on Map. Any alternative to this approach.

```
    Integer value;
    if((value = pageMap.get(key)) != null){            
        //execute code
    }
```

Comment: You are exchanging a slight optimization for less readability. make sure this is worth the optimization. Most of the time this is not the case. I would recommend choosing the readable option and only rewrite when you've identified a specific bottleneck. optimizing early usually creates hard to read code and generally doesn't hit the actual bottlenecks. don't forget, map.containsKey is likely a very fast lookup in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8+ you can use:

```
int value = pageMap.getOrDefault(key, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, though I would rather write it as:

```
Integer value = pageMap.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    // do something
}
```

What the map really contains is references to `Integer` objects, so aside from having fewer library calls there's less "magic" going on here in general.

Comment: But isn't there an overhead of unboxing `value` every time it is substituted for `int` data type.

Comment: If you mean to use the value more than a few times I would suggest unboxing it only once.